# Redcap Shapefile Error

Tags: java, regionalization

For some reason I am unable to import shapefiles in the form of point data to REDCAP.

Do these data points need projected coordinate systems?

I am aware that the sample size is 500 when double clicking the REDCAP file.

I am also encountering errors when using the command line to launch the application.

Java is not recognized as an internal or external command when trying to execute the code included in the manual to launch the application.  There are apparently memory unless launched from Java.  This enables working with larger data sets.

Neither polygons or points are opening, the data have been tested in a GCS and PCS.
The sample data opens without flaw.

http://www.spatialdatamining.org/software/redcap

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Redcap only accepts polygon shp files. The tool description on the link above only talks about polygon files.